# Why is the content not showing in a popover with dataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-5, popover

I am using dataTables for showing same data and I have a remarks column which I want to show in the table the first 30 characters but when I hover over the remark, then the whole remark must be visible in the popover.

This is the HTML:

```
<table id="aangeboden-ritten" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a data-toggle="popover" title="Remarks" data-content="Long remarks, here must come the full text" data-trigger="hover">Short remarks ...</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aangeboden-ritten').DataTable({
    fnDrawCallback : function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
    }
  });
});
```

A working Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arieanneke/ugz4ft3w/8/)

Any idea why I see only the title (Remarks) when I hover the remark but I don't see the long content?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: showing the title attribute while the mouse hovers over a DOM element is a browser feature; you need to hook into the mouseenter/mouseleave events - with jquery use: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @flowtron that makes zero sense.

Comment: You can also achieve this without using another third party plugin by using a render function in the `columnDefs` DataTable option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't working as you have not included the relevant libraries in the page. You need to reference jQuery, Bootstrap and Datatables.

Also note that your question is tagged with 'Bootstrap 5', yet the pattern you're following to invoke the Bootstrap popup and provide it with data imply you're using Bootstrap 4.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aangeboden-ritten').DataTable({
    fnDrawCallback: function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id="aangeboden-ritten" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a data-toggle="popover" title="Remarks" data-content="Long remarks, her must come the full text" data-trigger="hover">Short remarks ...</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tnx for the solution. I had included the libraries in my original files and indeed ....... I forgot them in the fidle :-(
But I know now what was going wrong, I use a bootstrap.bundle.min.js and after I changed this to bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js it was working fine.

Last question, if I change this to bootstrap@5.0.0 it isn't working anymore, what is the difference between them for the Bootstrap popup module?

Comment: Bootstrap 5 entirely changed how popovers work. You would need to update the HTML and JS logic completely. see [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/) for more info